# не могу вывести в файл сумму элементов матрицы под самой матрицей, если добавить f.write(str(sum)) пишет <built-in function sum>

Tags: python

```
def creator():
    n = int(input('Введите n ='))
    a = [[0] * n for i in range (n)]
    counter = 1
    sum = 0
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
        a[x][y] = counter
        counter += 1
        sum += a[x][y]
        print(a[x][y], end='\t')
    print()
    print(sum)
return a
with open('summa.txt', 'w')as f:
    for i in creator():
        f.write(str("\t".join(map(str, i))))
        f.write("\n")
    f. write(str(sum))
f.close()
```

Comment: даже если привязать sum к переменной ничего не меняется((

Comment: потому что sum - это зарезервированное слово python. назовите свою переменную по-другому.

Comment: я имею ввиду например: h = sum, уже после ее введения

Comment: при том в print до вывода в файл если написать print(h), то все в порядке

Comment: а я имею в виду то, что имею. sum - это зарезервированное слово python, встроенная функция sum(). и код в вопросе приведите так, чтобы было понятно, что у вас с отступами.

Comment: честно, я не понял что вы от меня хотите..

Comment: я от вас ничего не хочу. у вас не работает код. я вам предложил вместо имени переменной sum использовать другое имя, например mysum, и дважды объяснил почему. и предложил код отформатировать в вопрос так, чтобы было понятно что у вас с отступами, например в строке с return.

Comment: я не называю переменную этим именем, я хотел к некой переменной присвоить sum, но это не сработало, вопрос в том что нужно сделать что бы в файл выводилась сумма чисел в матрице

Comment: в вашем коде написано `sum = 0` . вы буквально присваиваете переменной sum значение 0.

Comment: я понял о чем вы, это нужно что бы в цикле посчитать сумму

Comment: да что с вам не так? я говорю, что НЕЛЬЗЯ ЭТО СЛОВО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ В КАЧЕСТВЕ НАЗВАНИЯ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ. короче, я умываю руки.

Comment: но иначе у меня не получится посчитать сумму всех элементов, по крайней мере другой метод я не знаю..

Comment: @Юрий, то есть, когда вам в комментариях неоднократно пишут, что нужно использовать другое имя переменной вместо `sum`, это непонятно, а вот когда то же самое говорится в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1488961/386633), всё сразу становится кристально ясно?

Comment: @Nowhere Man, я просто сразу не сообразил, глаз замылился, бывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно использовать другое имя для переменной суммы:

```
def creator():
    n = int(input('Введите n ='))
    a = [[0] * n for i in range (n)]
    counter = 1
    matrix_sum = 0
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            a[x][y] = counter
            counter += 1
            matrix_sum += a[x][y]
            print(a[x][y], end='\t')
        print()
    print(matrix_sum)
    return matrix_sum

with open('summa.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in a:
        f.write(str("\t".join(map(str, i))))
        f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(creator()))
f.close()
```

или даже так:

```
def creator():
    n = int(input('Введите n ='))
    a = [[0] * n for i in range (n)]
    counter = 1
    matrix_sum = 0
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            a[x][y] = counter
            counter += 1
            matrix_sum += a[x][y]
            print(a[x][y], end='\t')
        print()
    print(matrix_sum)
    return a,matrix_sum

with open('summa.txt', 'w') as f:
    matrix,matrix_sum = creator()
    for i in matrix:
        f.write(str("\t".join(map(str, i))))
        f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(matrix_sum))
f.close()
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, в глазу бревно не увидел